# Extra time when time is of the essence (U.S.)

Tags: exams, health, disability

In the U.S. context, I am wondering how colleges deal with the accommodation of students with disabilities when testing something for which "time is of the essence".

Consider, for example, a sight-reading exam at a music school. Surely, as much as dyslexia seriously impairs reading text, there must exist an equivalent condition impairing some people's ability to read music. So I would expect that under current policies, a student who can demonstrate a serious "music reading disability" could ask for accommodation in the form of extra time on a sight-reading exam (at least if the exam is one where students are given some time with the new sheet before they have to perform it live)?

The issue, obviously, is that time is of the essence in a sight-reading exam. What is being tested is precisely whether the student is able to *quickly* (sometimes even "on the spot") read a new sheet of music.

Of course, this extends beyond the particular example of sight-reading. A school that trains mechanics may specifically want to test whether its students are able to service a car *in a given amount of time*. A school that trains chemists may want to test whether its students can perform a given experiment *in a given amount of time* as well. And so on and so forth.

These situations seem hard to reconcile with requests for extra-time from students with disabilities. My questions are:

1. Do current accommodation policies recognize a "special kind of tests" where "time is of the essence" and requests for extra time from students with disabilities can legally be turned down?
2. If so, what prevents teachers from deciding that time is of the essence in all (or most) of their tests? In answers to other questions about extra time, we often read that "tests should test knowledge and understanding, not speed". What if a school decided it wanted to grant degrees to student who not only "understand" some material, but are also "quick on their feet" and able to apply this material to solve problems (or produce an artistic performance in the musical example above) in a timely manner? Could the school go down that road without contravening existing anti-discrimination regulations and risk losing all its public funding?

Comment: My understanding is that accommodations are always granted on a case-by-case basis, so this question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: Also, please ask just one question.

Comment: "what prevents teachers from deciding that time is of the essence in all (or most) of their tests?"  The instructor does not decide the accommodations.  Usually there is a dedicated office that makes those decisions.

Comment: Agreed, I am talking about the instructor deciding that "time is part of what they want to test", not whether accommodations are or aren't required. Doesn't the instructor decide what the tests in her class are testing, in this case, whether the ability to perform a task *in a given amount of time* is essential to what is being tested? Or is that also something the instructor is not totally free to decide on her own and depends --- to some extent at least --- on the accomodation office's approval?

Comment: Even if accommodations are granted on a case-by-case basis, there are general *policies* (and laws) that apply to accommodations, at least in the U.S. context. What these *policies* have to say about the cases I describe is what I am interested in.

Comment: Well, I just told you the laws and policies lead to case by case decisions on accommodations, and the instructor does not decide.  I don't think you will get a more helpful answer.

Comment: I think the term is "reasonable accommodation".  In the workplace, alcoholism is a disability.  Unpaid time off for treatment is a reasonable accommodation.  Allowing workers to operate heavy equipment drunk is an unreasonable accommodation.  Why wouldn't the same principle apply in academics?

Answer (score 2):

> Do current accommodation policies recognize a "special kind of tests"
>   where "time is of the essence" and requests for extra time from
>   students with disabilities can legally be turned down?

No.

For example, where I am, instructors receive a form simply saying, "Student X has a right to double time on exams". There is no sub-categorization made to that right, and no channel for instructors to pick or choose whether to honor it.

Comment: (+1) For an unambiguously explicit example of how the concerns of the OP are often moot in actual practice, despite how seemingly complex and significant the concerns might appear to an outsider.

Comment: This is not at all my experience.  Letters from our disabilities office state that, while students may be allowed extra time on examinations, that does not mean there are changes to what is being tested.  In particular, if a test score is based on how long it takes a student to complete a task, a student who receives accommodations for extra time will be graded the same way as all other students.

Answer (score -2):

Most institutions do make accomodation for this but you have to ask - there is no “one size fits all policy”.

This is because there are two sides: what the test is trying to achieve and what that particular student may need.

So you have to ask, the lecturer or the department or the learning disabilities officer.

Comment: This doesn't answer any part of the question.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist you make the same points in your comments above...

Comment: And I didn't post an answer.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist that’s why I called them comments...

Comment: To be clear, I am calling your answer a comment, and it seems you agree with me.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist you were not clear and I did not call my answer a comment... I made the comment that you called out my answer while making the same points...